# Where can I watch all three movies that have released after the first season of Kabaneri Of The Iron Fortress?

Tags: anime-production, crunchyroll, koutetsujou-no-kabaneri

Where can I watch all three movies that have released after the first season of ***Kabaneri Of The Iron Fortress?*** I really enjoyed this anime when I watched it on Amazon in 2016. I went looking to see if there was a second season in the works and found mentioned in this [article](https://trinikid.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-kabaneri-of-the-iron-fortress-season-2) that there have been three additional movies, however no second season. It looks like there are 2 compilation movies on [Crunchyroll]

- ***Kabaneri of the Iron Fortress: Light That Gathers***
- ***Kabaneri of the Iron Fortress: Life That Burns***

Would love to know what the name of third movie is and where to watch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third movie is named [Kabaneri of the Iron Fortress: The Battle of Unato](https://myanimelist.net/anime/34544/Koutetsujou_no_Kabaneri_Movie_3__Unato_Kessen)
and it is available on [Netflix](https://www.netflix.com/us/title/81095103).